# mysql - map username to an unique identifier

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP Mysql application.

In my User table, I have the username column that used for login. For some reason I should keep all usernames with no change forever. If the user wants to change it I should save new username and map it to original username.

What is the best implementation of this senario?

and what is the best way to implement login?

Comment: It's not a great idea, but you just store the username as if it was the id. So, you have two columns; id and username. Initially, they will both show the same value. The id will be PRIMARY and the username will be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

Well, on the backend... usernames shouldn't matter. You should be referencing their UserID table ID. If the user changes their username. The simplest way to implement would be to create a user alias table. So when they create their username, you add their "username" as an alias.... Example. If you create this mapping, you'll be doing a short-order DB cook all the time. Letting the users self-service is always easier than creating friction.

### Users table

```
Users
Id      UserName     email                pwhash            salt
------  -----------  -------------------- ----------------  ----------
1       superjoe     joseschmoe@gmail.com supersecretstuff  moresecretstuff
```

### Alias table

```
Aliases
Id      UsersID  UserAlias   datemodified
------  -------  ----------  -------------------
1       1        joeschmoe   2016-01-13 20:59:59
2       1        superjoe    2016-06-10 10:01:36
```

So you simply use a few statements on your PHP side for the creating new user and also for renaming the user.

Creating new account: (use bind_param for the ?)

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO aliases (userid, usersalias) SELECT id, username FROM users
WHERE username = '?';
```

Updating New Username:

```
/* Assuming you keep the userid in a variable in php.
 *  otherwise you will need to use a Select Statement to get the userid
 *  or just use the username.
 */
UPDATE USERS SET Username='?' WHERE userid = '?'; 
INSERT INTO aliases (userid, usersalias) SELECT id, username FROM users
WHERE username = '?';
```

Users can manage themselves on their own user profile page or something to that effect.

Here's the bind_param method I use in php for example. So, you would want the $mysqli somewhere on your backend for an include statement so you don't have to put this on every single page. Just include_once and you're good to use it for functions anywhere in your php pages.

```
define("HOST", "hostname");
define("USER", "dbuser");
define("PASSWORD", "supersecret");
define("DATABASE", "mydatabase");
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, pwhash, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    // Bind PHP Variables to the query.
    // ssss implies - string for each binded parameter
    // ssd for example would be string, string, decimal 
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: ../errorpage.php');
    }
}
header('Location: ./successpage.php);
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. How to find user with present username for login? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You can capture that information in their login when they sign in. $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

Answer (score 0):

For the mapping "new name to old name": The easiest way would be to just log the old name away and then update the username in the user table:

You can simply create a new table "usernameHistory" with columns userId, username, changeDate.

So when the user changes his name, you can just insert the old name into this table and change the name in the user table (use transaction so you are able to rollback if there is an error).

Does this fit your problem? There would be other solutions, but it depends on your usecase. I really hope this one works for you, everything else could turn out messy I think.

Other way:

If you really have to keep the dataset of the user in it's original state you have to insert the new username as a new dataset.

You then query for the id of the old username and update EVERY table in which the id is used to build relations between the user and other entities. (Don't forget to use transactions when doing this so you can rollback if something goes wrong)

If you don't have a identifier other than the username for the user, you have to touch every table involved in handling the relations to add an user-id as identifier.

Also you should add a column to the user-table in which you can flag if the dataset is active or not, so the user can't use the old name to login.

Answer (score 0):

Create one more new table with 3 important columns parent_user_id,username,created.In which parent_user_id refers to users primary id and username refers to multiple usernames that can be added.
In short you need to create 1:m mapping.
For more ease you can add in_use column in new table which would benefit you in many cases.